# Ipage Host key changing randomly

Tags: key, host

I have a problem when connecting to my Ipage server through SFTP.
The server changes the host key randomly, when I connect, disconnect, upload or download a file, so it causes a mismatch between the server's host an the one stored in my system, initially created the first time you connect and accept the key from the server.

I've contacted the support team and they told me that they were able to replicate my issue.
Now they say that everything is working properly for them, however it's not for me.

I've already deleted ssh known hosts file checked my client configuration a thousand times, disabled avast, firewall, accept the new keys etc... and I'm still getting the same warning message:

**"The server’s host key has changed since your last connection. This is most likely due to a server change, but you should check with your server administrator to be sure. Click OK to accept the new host key."**

I used to manage my websites through SFTP with no issues until now.
Does anybody know what could be wrong? or where should I look? They say the issue is originated from my end, but the server host key is the one that's changing.

Thanks in advance.